# 'If' statement on my client side is ignored by my function, even though it holds true

Tags: c#

```
public static void SendMessage(RobotProperties properties)
    {
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(properties);
        // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
        Byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(output);

        // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        Console.WriteLine("Sent:\n {0}", data);

        // Receive the TcpServer.response.
        // Buffer to store the response bytes.
        data = new Byte[1000];

        // Read the TcpServer response bytes into data buffer. stream.Read returns the number of bytes read which are stored into the bytes variable.
        Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        string dataReceived = Encoding.Default.GetString(data);
        Console.WriteLine("This was received: {0}", dataReceived);

        if (dataReceived.Equals("Received") && count<50)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Check if it gets here");
            properties.x -= 1;
            count++;
            SendMessage(properties);
        }
    }
```

The count is initialized to 0. Although the client does receive the data i.e 'Received' and count is below 50, it doesn't go within the if statement and make the recursive call. What might be going wrong ?

Comment: Case-sensitivity?

Comment: Does dataReceived equal “Received” or “received”?

Comment: "Received". Case sensitivity is not a problem.

Comment: Where is count initialized? if string is not case sensitive.

Comment: Hint: what does `Encoding.Default.GetString(data).Length` return? There is a reason for the return value of `stream.Read`.

Comment: Any spaces at the end of "Received" that you may not be seeing?

Comment: Console.WriteLine("This is count: {0}", count); What is output?

Comment: Is the variable "count" static? can you show how it has been initialized?

Comment: There is no reason to make a recursive call. Make a loop. Also, [Debug your C# or Visual Basic .NET Core Hello World application using Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/debugging-with-visual-studio?tabs=csharp).

Comment: Ahh. Yes that was the problem. The length of the string is 1000, equal to the byte array initialized. From what I remembered previously, using Encoding.Default.GetString would trim the spaces at the end. It didn't though somewhy. Thanks Guys.